# How to convert List of Arrays into single Array using python when all array have different dimensions

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, list

I have a list of arrays, each array with different dimension like:

`list=[array([[1,2,3],[1,4,6],[5,7,8]]),array([[1,2,3,7,8],[1,4,6,9,10],[5,7,8,11,12],[5,3,7,8,9]])]`

how I can make it to single array like below:

`array([

   [[1,2,3],[1,4,6],[5,7,8]],

   [[1,2,3,7,8],[1,4,6,9,10],[5,7,8,11,12],[5,3,7,8,9]]

   ])`

I used vstack, concatenate function but it gives me error

`ValueError: all the input array dimensions except for the concatenation axis must match exactly`

Editing: 
This is actually image matrix with different size of 3D images that is height and width for each image is different and channel is same for each image .

like (117,121,389) , (84,121,389)

So finally I got to know either I can crop or add padding of numpy zeros.

Any other suggestions what can be done.

Comment: can you post your python script please